# JFile Chooser throwing errors before use, only sometimes?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I create a JFile Chooser, and use .setCurrentDirectory(); to set the Directory to the root of my java project folder by passing a newFile("."); This seems to work fine sometimes, but other times it throws an error. This all happens while the program is loading, before any user input, so as far as I can tell it's completely random whether it happens or not. Here's the File Chooser related bits of my code:

```
public class PnlHighScores extends JPanel {

    JFileChooser fcScores = new JFileChooser();

    PnlHighScores() {

        fcScores.addChoosableFileFilter(new TxtFilter());

        //***********This seems to cause a strange error only somethimes, Right as the program is run!***********
        fcScores.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));//http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0370.html
    }


    class ActFileChooser implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java
            int returnVal = fcScores.showOpenDialog(PnlHighScores.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filScores = fcScores.getSelectedFile();
                sFileLocation = filScores.getAbsolutePath();//.getParent();//http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/29485-how-retrieve-path-filechooser.html
                //System.out.println(filScores);
                pnlScoreText.updateScoreFile(sFileLocation);
            }

        }
    }
    class TxtFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {//http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.filechooser/Filter.html

        public boolean accept(File file) {
            String filename = file.getName();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return filename.endsWith(".txt");
            }
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "*.txt";
        }
    }
}
```

The exact error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
        at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:497)
        at sun.swing.FilePane$SortableListModel.getElementAt(FilePane.java:528)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1343)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1294)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getCellBounds(BasicListUI.java:935)
        at javax.swing.JList.getCellBounds(JList.java:1600)
        at javax.swing.JList.ensureIndexIsVisible(JList.java:1116)
        at sun.swing.FilePane.ensureIndexIsVisible(FilePane.java:1540)
        at sun.swing.FilePane.doDirectoryChanged(FilePane.java:1466)
        at sun.swing.FilePane.propertyChange(FilePane.java:1513)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:339)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:276)
        at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8128)
        at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(JFileChooser.java:568)
        at Cannon.PnlSettings.<init>(PnlSettings.java:45)
        at Cannon.FraWindow.<init>(FraWindow.java:19)
        at Cannon.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Java Result: 1
```

The Main class simply creates FraWindow, and FraWindow Creates PnlSetting through its constructor method. They should be irrelavent, but here's main just in case:

```
package Cannon;

//Creates the frame
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FraWindow fraMain = new FraWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the exception that is being thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This all happens while the program is loading,

All code that affects the GUI should execute on the Event Dispatch Thread. The creation of the GUI should be wrapped in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information. And look at any of the examples that demonstrate the proper way to create the GUI.

Comment: Thank you. Ironically I just added this moments ago because I was looking through my CS teachers notes and he recommended it for a different problem I was having. Either way, this was very helpful, and I can now rest knowing its fixed.

Comment: this is exactly why i wanted to see the main class! glad your problem got solved!